# Paypal IPN, But From Who (if the registration and paypal mail different)

Tags: php, paypal

I am having trouble with Paypal IPN About one thing,

As I understood, paypal redirects the user to a page of us after the successful order, then calls our IPN page, after the transection with post variables including result.

Paypal sends the mail of the order owner in the post variables, but what if the mail in the site and paypal are different.

If PayPal is calling the ipn page, sessions won't work. If i don't check the mail, I won't be able to catch simultaneously IPN orders ( I think ).

I saw something about `txn_id` and `receipt_id`, but if I'am not sending the variables, how can they help me to catch the user.

I am Mixed a bit.

Thanks for any reply.
Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a custom parameter, it can be user to send additional parameters

Answer (score -1):

You link the IPN request and the transaction by the `txn_id` (transaction_id). This is an id you generate, the only requirement is that it's unique.

So:

1. User starts a payment transaction on your site. You generate a `transaction_id` which is linked to the user with address info and some 'shopping cart', price info, items etc. This is all the info you need, to know who ordered what and where to send it - all identified by the `transaction_id`
2. You pass your merchant info and `transaction_id` on to PayPal.
3. User completes payment.
4. IPN calls your server with user info, payment status and a `transaction_id`. The `email address` you get from PayPal may be a different `email address` than you have registered for the user, maybe the user has a separate email for PayPal? .. It doesn't matter. Use the email address the user gave *you*, not the one you got from PayPal. And don't use the `email address` for identification, use the `transaction id` it's the only value you can rely on.

I'm not sure about the `receipt_id`. If you want to email a `receipt`, mail it after you've got a successful payment from IPN. You should have all the info to generate the receipt.

Comment: Hello it seems paypal generates the transaction id, not me. Are you sure about this? İ posted to sandbox the txn_id but it is totally different and in html variables text of paypal, transection id is not an option. they post this variable to prevent double ipns in your site.

Comment: Correct, `transaction_id` is a transaction ID generated by PayPal. `receipt_id` is only applicable when guest buyers without a PayPal account check out, and isn't really necessary to look at. Moreover, the `transaction_id` for a buyer is different from the `transaction_id` for a seller, because they're two different actions (transaction 1: debit buyer, transaction 2: credit seller).

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, paypal sends my transaction_id(as txn_id) back to me as post, different from it's own transaction_id shown to buyer. This way, we are able to authenticate the users. Thanks.

Comment: As I read from different sources, there is no transaction id or txn_id that I receive from pay-pal or any identifier helps me to check ID related with the user. It is enough to check the transaction_id of pay-pal. Still mixed about conflations. But All is well then.